# How to create Oracle DB triggers for this example?

Tags: database, oracle11g, triggers

I would like to know how to implement triggers on two tables so that data integrity and consistency is maintained.

I have table1 (t1_id, product_name, t2_id, manufacture_name) and table2 (t2_id, manufacture_name)..

I need Update trigger on table2.manufacture_name. When this name changes it is auto updated in table1 (in all rows where that name is present).

I need Insert trigger for table1 when t2_id is entered it auto inserts value for manufacture_name.

I need Update trigger when updating t2_id in table1 to auto update manufacture_name in table1 from table2 and i need Update trigger that will disallow changing manifacture_name in table1 because it's value is read from table2.

Tnx.

Comment: Just drop the manufacturer name in T1 and you don't need any triggers anymore. Problem solved.

Comment: I already did that using denormalization but I need triggers to maintain data integrity... Because of performance I denormalized tables but I need to have both tables in database.

Comment: Perhaps you should look to see why you think you need to demoralize in the first place

Comment: I managed to implement all triggers that I needed except update trigger where I need to update another column in the same table where some column is changed but value is stored in another table. Example table1(t1_id, product, manufacture_id, manufacture_name) and table2 (manufacture_id, manufacture_name). When I update manufacture_id in table1 I need to update value in t1.manufacture_name from t2.manifacture_name..

Comment: Perhaps, may be you can drop the manufacturer name in the table1 and create a view on top of table1 and add the manufacturer to the view.